# Memory using lists - Homework

Tags: c, list, memory, scheme

So basically I'm struggling with question 5 in this assignment, http://www.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~cs136/assignments/a5/

We are basically given functions that act like Scheme list functions and in question 5 I am supposed to create a function called `iappend`, which appends two lists. This is my code and it seems to work.

```
ilist iappend(ilist il1, ilist il2) {
    ilist acc = iempty();
    ilist acc1 = iempty();
    ilist a;
    while (!iempty_huh(il1)) {
        acc1 = icons(ifirst(il1), acc1);
        il1 = irest(il1);
    }
    while (!iempty_huh(il2)) {
        acc1 = icons(ifirst(il2), acc1);
        il2 = irest(il2);
    }
    a = acc1;
    while (!iempty_huh(acc1)) {
        acc = icons(ifirst(acc1), acc);
        acc1 = irest(acc1);
    }
    idelete(a);
    return acc;
}
```

New Problem, can somewone help me code, so i won't make a temporary list ? I need to code it in such a way that i won't use idelete .... any suggestions would help :)

Comment: I think it is still O(n), but it could certainly be made a FASTER O(n).  You're doing a fixed number of passes over the lists, and you need to make at least ONE pass over at least ONE of the lists.

Comment: I'm not shure i understand what,"  make at least ONE pass over at least ONE of the lists" means?

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, you are to mimic the recursive solution by using auxiliary lists as stack, and you have that idea.
But to be more efficient, try this.  Make a reversed copy of the first list first, with just a simple while-not-empty loop.  Then continue extending that reversed copy with the second list, again with a simple while-not-empty loop.  Now you have a reversed copy of the two lists appended together: (reverse second)||(reverse first); make a reversed-reversed (i.e. correct order) copy of that with yet another while-not-empty loop.  You should be able to do this without any "if" tests -- the while loops should handle the empty list corner cases correctly.

Also, don't delete the arguments -- that's asking for trouble.  But of course do delete the reversed copy made by the first two loops and used by the third;  it is in essence the recursive version's stack.

Comment: when i have the reversed second list, shouldn't i make a reversed copy of the first too and then keep on extending the reversed copy?

Comment: I have interpretated this:
ilist iappend(ilist il1, ilist il2){
ilist acc = iempty();
ilist acc1 = iempty();
ilist a;
while(!iempty_huh(il1)){
acc1 = icons(ifirst(il1),acc1);
il1 = irest(il1);
}

while(!iempty_huh(il2)){
acc1 = icons(ifirst(il2),acc1);
il2 = irest(il2);
}
a = acc1;
while(!iempty_huh(acc1)){
acc = icons(ifirst(acc1), acc);
acc1 = irest(acc1);
}
idelete(a);
return acc;
}

Comment: it doesn't seem to keep on accumlating the reversed second list onto to it thou?

Answer (score 1):

Two hints:  (pop, push) , one loop

additional hint

if iList is a struct of { item, next_iList_ptr } you can copy your value and point to the next node     for the next iteration on the list. switch to the second after the first is done.

Comment: one loop sounds interesting. but i dont quite understand push and pop ?

Comment: You appear to be dealing with a singly linked list. You can only traverse stack-like from beginning to end. So the append is popping nodes off l1 pushing into l3, hitting the end of l1, popping l2 pushing into l3, then returning l3. It can be done in one while loop. It was not clear from your post whether l1 or l2 would be changed.

Comment: So a loop in a loop, but won't i still be making a temp list? and no l1 and l2 shouldn't be changed (so i assumed to make a temp list), we suppose to make a new "list" using l1 and l2

Comment: i made into one loop useing if and else staments but that still gets me the reversed orginal list? is there a way to code this makeing no temp lists?

Comment: If I understand your rules, you can operate directly on iList nodes. There is no need, and it is more efficient, than using iempty-irest-icons.

Comment: im new with pointer's can you give me an example on what you mean by, "work directly on ilist nodes"

Comment: Hard to answer without answering for you, but here's a try. I'll edit my comment.

Comment: So are you saying i can "pop" specific item's from the inputed list? rather than on the first of those list's?

Comment: and i think they expect to use the functions they provided, iunno how to make my code more efficient thou

Answer (score 0):

Roughly put: scoot over the first list, making a copy, and remember the last cell of the copy; then build a copy of the second list from that.

Comment: Don't think he has rplacd, so he has to double-reverse.

Comment: so save a copy of the first list in reverse order(i assume cause i want to remember the last cell), when i build a copy of the second list, should't i somewone accumlate both lists together. Prof also said i don't need idelete in my function so i assume i need only one variable to store the output list.... this is where i struggle